# Как работает adapter.js для WebRTC?

Tags: html5, webrtc

Он просто предопределяет стандартизированные функции вендорными или у него есть свое API ? Если есть свое API, можно ссылку на документацию, в гугле доки не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

`adapter.js` это некая штука которая включает в себя все api для поддержки `WebRTC`.

Согласно [этой ссылке](https://webrtc.org/web-apis/interop/) между chrome и firefox есть некие различия и эта "библиотека" эти различия убирает тем что определение что именно использовать, будь то API хрома или же API фокса лежит на ней. Ну а мы же просто используем то одно что предоставляет нам `adapter.js`.

Если дословно:

> adapter.js is a shim to insulate apps from spec changes and prefix
>   differences. In fact, the standards and protocols used for WebRTC
>   implementations are highly stable, and there are only a few prefixed
>   names. For full interop information, see webrtc.org/web-apis/interop.

Взято с офф репозитория на [github](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter)